# How to add an animated legend with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add an animated legend that would update the y-values, can someone help me with this please.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


x_min = 0
x_max = 3.5
y_min = 0
y_max = 500
y_vals = range(y_min, y_max+1)

def update_line(num, line):
    i = y_vals[num]
    line.set_data([x_min, x_max], [i,i])
    return line,



fig = plt.figure()
#x = arange(y_min, y_max, 10)
l, v = plt.plot(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, color='red')
line_anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, len(y_vals),fargs=(l,))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to achieve? How should the legend change during animation? Your current code produces an animation in which a horizontal red line moves upward; what has to appear in the legend?

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation, I'm trying to make a legend that would display the changing y-values simultaneously while the red horizontal line is moving upward.